# Frontend flickering

Tags: front-end, dynamic, cells, hyperlink

The front end is flickering on hyperlink mouse-over events:

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this, or any option that could boost the front end's frame rate for mouse related dynamic events?

Comment: Is this version 10.4? What OS? Looks like a case for Wolfram support.

Comment: I've seen this behavior since v9 on and off... this is 10.4 on OS X 10.10.5

Comment: Hmmm, not sure why someone voted this to be closed, seems rather pertinent and huge bugs like these should be tracked historically.

Comment: You shouldn't add the bugs tag until someone else explicitly reproduces the behavior. For that, it will be important to provide copyable code to reproduce the phenomenon. If it can't be reproduced, then it will be closed. If it's a case where only Wolfram can help and no workaround exists, it will most likely also be closed, but it's too early to say...

Comment: These types of front end bugs are almost impossible to duplicate.

Comment: If you put in the code that generated the link, I'll try it.